# pyexpect alternative for windows

Tags: python, expect

a friend of mine is searching for some alternative of pyexpect for windows, capable to run a binary and to feed its inputs and read outputs. Although we have made certain effort using google, still no success. Using pyexpect + cygwin is not the option here. Hence, here comes the question: does anyone know about anything? :-)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why doesn't pyexpect work for you? What requirement is making you seek an alternative?

Comment: As far as I know, pyexpect works only on posix OS, hence UN*Xes but not on windozes...

Answer (score 0):

How about using [actual Expect](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/expect4win/)?